Yocto bitbake core-image-minimal
I'm trying to create an image of bitbake but I simply can't. If I do it on Root it gives me a sanity error if I bypass it, it doesn't let me run it.
So my next approach was to create a user, make it sudo root and go from there, but when I get to the sudo -s source poky/oe-init-build-env, I need,as you saw, to use sudo -s if I don't it simply doesn't like it, once I do it, all good.
However when I reach the bitbake core-image-minimal, it spwes the following error:
Unable to create 'pyshtables.py'
[Errno 13] Permission denied: 'pyshtables.py'
ERROR: Unable to acquire lock '/build/bitbake.lock', directory is not writable
etc..
ERROR: Unable to connect to bitbake server, or start one (server startup failures would be in bitbake-cookerdaemon.log).

It doesn't let me and if I try to run like before using sudo and shell, it gives this instead:
/bin/bash: line 1: bitbake: command not found

I'm running this on a docker Ubuntu and I'm seriously at a loss, any guide (videos) that I look up doesn't have this issue and they simply run it like it was the easiest thing to setup.
All help is appreciated, thank you.

I got your problem. Yocto never works as root user. So, you have to run it this way. As you are working in docker container which most probably only contains a root user.
So, you have to work this way

First create a custom user. You can follow this article to create a new user and switch to that user as done in this link. It is creating a new user and adding it to sudoers and then switching to that user using su command https://phoenixnap.com/kb/how-to-create-sudo-user-on-ubuntu
After doing all things given in above article, clone all the sources required for yocto such as poky and other sources.
Now, open the terminal in a folder where you have downloaded/cloned the poky and run the command "source poky/oe-init-build-env build"

Now run the command "bitbake core-image-minimal"


Thank you!! I decided to create a docker file which updates the image and also creates a user with root privileges and a password. However, when I run the command (bitbake core-image-minimal) everything works but then I get that it's trying to look up an older version of iptables (8 something) while a newer is available

Do ignore, I think this happened because I lost connection. I reran the bitbake on a clean docker and it finished without issues

Yes, using dockerfile is a clean and efficient way to do it. And that's great it worked for you!

However, I have this new error with tap:
         runqemu - ERROR - Setting up tap device failed:

Command '('sudo', '/home/yocto/poky/scripts/runqemu-ifup', '1000', '1000', '/home/yocto/build/tmp/work/x86_64-linux/qemu-helper-native/1.0-r1/recipe-sysroot-native/usr/bin')' returned non-zero exit status 1

please show me the complete command you are executing for running qemu

Furthermore, let me imagine how qemu can be run inside the docker as it is a sort of another virtual machine or hypervisor within docker.

run docker container by appending --privileged flag and then try to run qemu inside it. Maybe it works then

I'm running the following commands: runqemu and runqemu qemuarm (I never remember correctly how it is the one for arm) as I'm following a youtube guide, although it's pretty outdated on it. I think that just running runqemu is fine in this case seeing as I only have one in the docker. Also, I thought of the same but assumed it would be fine

and I've been using git clone --branch kirkstone git://git.yoctoproject.org/poky

if you select MACHINE ?= "qemuarm64/qemuarm" in conf/local.conf, then you can install qemu-system-arm or qemu-system-aarch64 in your docker and run qqemu using this command. However, if your machine is MACHINE ?= "qemux86_64", then run, runqemu qemux86_64 command

Would I run qemu-system-arm or qemu-system-aarch64 after booting up the docker and setting the MACHINE = "qemuarm64/qemuarm" or before that?
